# How to change color of editor indent in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the One Dark Pro theme but I don't like the color highlighting of indent.

[image]

This setting doesn't help:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#9e9e9e"
},
```

It is not `editorIndentGuide` because I cannot even turn them off with:

```json
"editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess these are drawn by [Bracket Pair Colorizer 2](https://github.com/CoenraadS/Bracket-Pair-Colorizer-2) extension, so if you want to get rid of those "bracket scope" lines, try to configure

```
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.showVerticalScopeLine": false,
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.showHorizontalScopeLine": false,
```

(and restart VSCode; on my install this change in config does not catch up upon save).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the accepted answer, these lines are drawn by your Bracket Pair Colorizer 2 extension. Currently, the extension will always draw those "bracket scope" lines using the **color of that matching bracket**. From your example, since you selected the purple parenthesis, the bracket scope line is purple in color.

As a workaround, you can customize the colors used to colorize the brackets using the following option:

```json
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.colors": [
    "Gold",
    "LightSkyBlue",
    "#ff0000",  // <-- eg. Replace the purple color ("Orchid") with a red color
],
```

[image: red brackets]

Feel free to replace the red color HEX code (`#ff0000`) to whatever color you like. You can [visit the extension's README page](https://github.com/CoenraadS/Bracket-Pair-Colorizer-2#settings) to learn how you can customize the extension settings.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the bracket-pair-colorizer-2 are [deprecated (2022-03-24)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2/changelog), the new solution is:

```json
{
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,

  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#ffe625",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#00ff15",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#25deff",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#c825ff",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground5": "#ff0077",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#ff803b",
    "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff0000"
  }
}
```

Another [solution](https://github.com/CoenraadS/Bracket-Pair-Colorizer-2/blob/78bef913fb99c509b1ca294e0e010de3a1e15db6/README.md#how-to-enable-native-bracket-matching) from deprecated bracket-pair-colorizer-2.

Comment: To be more preside: ` "editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active",` are what you're looking for.

Comment: Does this not work with Python? When I try it, I just get grey vertical lines, one line per level of indentation. The active indent is a bolder grey, almost white.